# Making a pubsub function that starts running at a specific time

Tags: javascript, firebase, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a scheduled pubsub functions that runs every 2 hours to clear some data.

```
exports.dataCleaner = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 */2 * * *')
  .onRun(() => { 
    console.log('clear some data');
  });
```

How do i make so this function STARTS executing at 00:00 UTC.

I still want the function to execute every 2 hours but i want the timer to start at that specific time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules) reference the [Linux docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) for `crontab`.  If I understand those correctly, the command string you need is: `0 0-23/2 * * *`. Your code would be:

```
exports.dataCleaner = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0-23/2 * * *')
  .onRun(() => { 
    console.log('clear some data');
  });
```

Comment: Weirdly enough we tried that and it didn't work but 0 */2 * * * worked.
Possibly that firebase doesn't like 0-23